# How to avoid summing duplicates when converting COO to CSR matrix

Tags: python, matrix

When converting the COO matrix to the CSR format the duplicates get summed. In the earler versions of scipy there was an flag `sum_duplicates=False`, but now it is gone. Is there a way to convert COO to CSR matrix without summing the duplicates?

Below is an example generating a coo matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix,coo_matrix

i_tar = np.array([3,3,3,3,3,6,7,8,8,2,2,2])
j_src = np.array([8,8,8,8,8,5,7,18,18,4,4,4])
data = np.array([3,4,6,8,40,6,12,5,6,2,3,9])

coo_mat = coo_matrix((data, (i_tar,j_src)),shape=(20,20))

print coo_mat
```

> ```
>   (3, 8)  3
>   (3, 8)  4
>   (3, 8)  6
>   (3, 8)  8
>   (3, 8)  40
>   (6, 5)  6
>   (7, 7)  12
>   (8, 18) 5
>   (8, 18) 6
>   (2, 4)  2
>   (2, 4)  3
>   (2, 4)  9
> ```

Converting it to the CSR format we find:

```
print coo_mat.tocsr()
```

> ```
>   (2, 4)  14
>   (3, 8)  61
>   (6, 5)  6
>   (7, 7)  12
>   (8, 18) 11
> ```

which has duplicates summed. I imaging there are good reasons for summing the duplicates, however, it is not what I need.

Comment: What is the expected output? The sum is the standard way to show it, Hyuck Kang gives another solution (choose final row). What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
coo_mat.todia().tocsr()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14090805)

Comment: @JamesK You are right. My answer is imperfect. Frankly, I'm not good at English. So I thought long sentence can invoke unnecessary misunderstanding. I assumed that he doesn't want summation conversion because all duplicated coordinates has same value. I had same problem when I constructed FEM stiffness matrix. Hence, I wrote this short answer to be probably needed. Thank you for your advices and links.